# What does this rapper mean by "swagger on super"?

Tags: meaning

In a song called "Fancy" by Iggy Azalea, she raps:
"Swagger on super, I can't shop at no department"

What does she mean by "swagger on super"?

If you know this catchy hip hop already, please help me understand this part of the lyrics.

[Here](http://iggyazalea.com/music/fancy/fancy), you'll see the full lyrics after you click off the pop-up.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-zpOMYRi0w), you can listen to the entire song *(it's at 1m 10s in there, and there's currently some debate as to exactly what the third word is - feel free to listen and comment [FumbleFingers]).*

Comment: [Here](http://www.mtv.com/news/1825931/iggy-azalea-jimmy-kimmel-lyrics-for-old-people/) is a translation.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already seen the Jimmy Kimmel's clip which doesn't cover as far as the OP.

Comment: You are the OP.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about lyrics interpretation.

Comment: Off topic due to bad song.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: I could stand the occasional question about lyrics in actual *songs* - but being a grumpy ole git, I can't bring myself to class rap as songs/music. About the closest I get is DJ Danger Mouse [The Grey Album](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Grey_Album), and I'm sure hardcore rap fans wouldn't call that rap anyway.

Comment: I am more old school on rap.  But for stuff like this.  Maybe it had a meaning to them or maybe it was just words that sounded good together.  Holy cow don't ever try to figure out what Springsteen was talking about.  Between incoherent lyrics and his mumbling.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd [Weird Al](http://youtu.be/m0shG9zC6oU) has now covered this "song".

Answer (score 1):

OP has mistranscribed the lyric. From [rapgenius.com](http://rapgenius.com/Iggy-azalea-fancy-lyrics#note-2978788)...

> *Swagger on **stupid,** I can't shop at no department*
>
> Iggy is saying because she is drowning in so much cash, her swag has risen to such a high extremity that is has now become “stupid”, implying that it’s completely silly and unbelievable for just one person to be that hot.
>
> Because of this luxurious life style, a department store is a shopping retailer you won’t find Iggy caught dead in.

Comment: Thanks, but the first link in the OP is to the rapper's official site and its the official lyrics. So, it's not "swagger on stupid" but "swagger on super". Sometimes, the lyrics on rapgenius.com are incorrect.

Comment: Mistranscription is on Iggy's official web-site. Who needs an "editor"?

Comment: @JK2: I don't generally listen to rap, and despite posting this answer, I've closevoted as Off Topic anyway. But you've goaded me into listening, and it seems clear to me the *official* site must be wrong. I hear ***stupid***, not ***super***.

Comment: If you're right and the official site has its lyrics wrong, how lame is that?!

Comment: @JK2 do you mean _Lamé_ ?

Comment: @JK2: Pretty lame, obviously. But surely *you* must have been led to wonder about this after listening to the "song" in the first place. My hearing is perhaps not as sharp as it once was, but I don't think there's much room for doubt on this one (it's at 1m 10s within your link). What did ***you*** hear?

Comment: Quite often, lyrics do sound ambiguous as to what the actual word is. In this particular case, it does sound like "stupid" but I cannot rule out "super" either. More important, all the lyric sites I've found so far (dozens of them) all say it's "super". Also, all the lyrics video I've seen so far on YouTube say it's "super". Go figure!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It took me three times to realise they were singing, I was too busy looking at booty. However, it's just possible she is referring to _Supaman_ (you may have considered this already) and informing him to _keep on walking_, or even a reference to Shaqs _blaq supaman_ or perhaps her current boyfriend (also a Lakers player) Nick Young who is nick-named _Swaggy P._ But I know you knew all that already.